# How to Make Div Push Over When the Div it's Beside Animates?

Tags: jquery, css, css-float

Hi There I have been trying everything to no avail. I am using the jQuery Interface script, which creates a fisheye effect on hover ala the mack Dock. It works fine and great. I want to have another image or div that sits inline beside the dock that gets pushed over when the dock effect happens. Right now the image just sits underneath the dock and moves only marginally. I've trin inline stylings, floats etc  Please see here http://kerrydean.ca/new_layout.html

Here is the CSS

```
#dock_wrap {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 15;
    margin-top:25px;
    text-align: center;
}
#dock2 {
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 3;
}
.dock-container2 {
    position: absolute;
    height: 70px;
    background: url(images/dock-bg.gif);
    padding-left: 20px;
}
a.dock-item2 {
    display: block; 
    font: bold 12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    width: 40px; 
    color: #4C215B; 
    bottom: 0px; 
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.dock-item2 span {
    display: none;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
.dock-item2 img {
    border: none; 
    margin: 5px 10px 0px; 
    width: 100%; 
}
```

Here is the HTML

```
<div id="dock_wrap">
        <div class="dock" id="dock2">
        <div class="dock-container2">
          <div><img src="kd_images/Kerry_Dean_Nav_1.jpg" width="264" height="70" /></div>
          <a class="dock-item2" href="blog.php"><span>Home</span><img src="kd_images/home.png" alt="home" /></a> <a class="dock-item2" href="kerry_on.html"><span>Kerry On</span><img src="kd_images/kerry_on.png" alt="kerry on" /></a>
          <a href="http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100000414102424" target="_blank" class="dock-item2"><span>Facebook</span><img src="kd_images/facebook.png" alt="contact" /></a> 
          <a href="http://twitter.com/kerrydeandotca" target="_blank" class="dock-item2"><span>Twitter</span><img src="kd_images/twitter.png" alt="video" /></a> 
          <a href="http://www.youtube.com/user/KerryDeanChocolate" target="_blank" class="dock-item2"><span>Youtube</span><img src="kd_images/youtube.png" alt="music" /></a> 
          <a href="http://chocolatebiztools.soundconcepts.com/index.php/chocolate-tastings-101-2nd-edition.html" target="_blank" class="dock-item2"><span>Buy Kerry's CD</span><img src="kd_images/cd.png" alt="video" /></a> 
          <a class="dock-item2" href="photos.html"><span>Photos</span><img src="kd_images/camera.png" alt="home" /></a> </div>
        </div>
    </div>
      <!-- end of dock wrap -->
```

Here is the JQuery

```
$(document).ready(
        function()
        {
            $('#dock2').Fisheye(
                {
                    maxWidth: 60,
                    items: 'a',
                    itemsText: 'span',
                    container: '.dock-container2',
                    itemWidth: 35,
                    proximity: 80,
                    alignment : 'left',
                    valign: 'bottom',
                    halign : 'center'
                }
            )
        }
    );
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: I must admit that I like the most the little bullets that appear (but delayed!) in the navigation menu. Are you serious about that page and the Fisheye 'effect' that hides the main page logo? Can you please be more specific on what are you trying to achieve in there?

Comment: I will get a js fiddle up this eve. But it's the fisheye effect I'm talking about. I want the logo that appears underneath to apper beside the dock and push over when the dock expands

Comment: What if you moved the KerryDean image outside the dock-container div?  Would that make a difference?

Comment: ok here is the js fiddle. Any help is greatly appreciated. http://jsfiddle.net/WrmAR/